# How to display string from action result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

there is a action: /Home/GetName, and return a string "Mike", the controller and  action like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Mike";
    }
}
```

how can I display this action result in view? (without ajax is better)

Comment: Have you created a view? Why are you returning typeof `string`? You should be returning a `ViewResult` or `ContentResult`

Comment: 1.Create a View 2. pass the var "name" to the View with model/ViewData 3. output the model/viewdata

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `ContentResult` to return string like

```
public ActionResult GetName() {
    return Content("Mike");
}
```

Note that by default a type of text/plain is returned by `ContentResult`.

Comment: i am asking how to display in view, a partialview. like <html> /Home/GetName (display Mike here)</html>